# Status of invoice in partner ledger report

Tags: python-2.7, openerp-7, odoo-8

I want to add status(open, paid,draft) of customer invoice in partner ledger report for each invoice.
I am try to add the status of customer invoice in partner ledger report in odoo 8.

This is the template where i am going to inherit:

```
<template id="report_partnerledger">
<t t-call="report.html_container">
    <t t-call="report.internal_layout">
        <div class="page">
            <h2>Partner Ledger</h2>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <strong>Chart of Accounts:</strong>
                    <p t-esc="get_account(data)"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <strong>Fiscal Year:</strong>
                    <p t-esc="get_fiscalyear(data)"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <strong>Journals:</strong>
                    <p t-esc="', '.join([ lt or '' for lt in get_journal(data) ])"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <strong>Partner's</strong>
                    <p t-esc="get_partners()"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <strong>Filter By:</strong>
                    <p>
                        <span t-if="data['form']['filter'] == 'filter_no'">Not filtered</span>
                        <span t-if="data['form']['filter'] == 'filter_period'">Filtered by period</span>
                        <span t-if="data['form']['filter'] == 'filter_date'">Filtered by date</span>
                        <p t-if="data['form']['filter'] == 'filter_period'">
                            Start Period: <span t-esc="get_start_period(data)"/>
                            End Period: <span t-esc="get_end_period(data)"/>
                        </p>
                        <p t-if="data['form']['filter'] == 'filter_date'">
                            Date from : <span t-esc="formatLang(get_start_date(data), date=True)"/><br />
                            Date to : <span t-esc="formatLang(get_end_date(data), date=True)"/>
                        </p>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <strong>Target Moves:</strong>
                    <p t-esc="get_target_move(data)"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <table class="table table-condensed">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>JRNL</th>
                        <th>Ref</th>
                        <th>Account</th>
                        <th>Entry Label</th>
                        <th>Debit</th>
                        <th>Credit</th>
                        <th>Balance</th>
                        <th t-if="amount_currency">Currency</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="partner">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="5">
                                <strong t-esc="partner.ref"/>
                                - <strong t-esc="partner.name"/>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <strong t-esc="sum_debit_partner(partner)"/>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <strong t-esc="sum_credit_partner(partner)"/>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <strong t-esc="formatLang((sum_debit_partner(partner) - sum_credit_partner(partner)), currency_obj=res_company.currency_id)"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr t-if="initial_balance">
                        <td colspan="5">Initial Balance</td>
                        <td>
                            <span t-esc="formatLang(get_intial_balance(partner)[0][0])"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span t-esc="formatLang(get_intial_balance(partner)[0][1])"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span t-esc="formatLang(get_intial_balance(partner)[0][2], currency_obj=res_company.currency_id)"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr t-foreach="lines(partner)" t-as="line">
                        <td>
                            <span t-esc="formatLang(line['date'], date=True)"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span t-esc="line['code']"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span t-esc="line['move_name']"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span t-esc="line['a_code']"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span t-esc="line['ref']"/>-<span t-esc="line['name']"/>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <span t-esc="formatLang((line['debit']))"/>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <span t-esc="formatLang((line['credit']))"/>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <span t-esc="formatLang(line['progress'], currency_obj=res_company.currency_id)"/>
                        </td>
                        <td t-if="amount_currency">
                            <span t-esc="formatLang(line['amount_currency'])"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </t>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </t>
</t>
```

for this I added the code:

```
<template id="account_partner_ledger_other_custom" inherit_id="account.report_partnerledgerother">
    <xpath expr="//thead/tr" position="inside">
        <th>Status</th>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

By doing this I am able to add the line STATUS on the partner ledger report but I am not able to show the status(paid, open or draft) in partner ledger report.
How can I do so?

Comment: As written, there is not nearly enough information in this question for us to help. It's hard to even know what information to start asking for. Some sample code showing what you've tried would go a very long way.

Comment: @jpmc26  yes you are right ..

Comment: I have added the code now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this using the below:

```
self.cr.execute(
        "SELECT l.id, l.date, j.code, acc.code as a_code, acc.name as a_name, l.period_id, inv.state, inv.date_due, l.ref, m.name as move_name, l.name, l.debit, l.credit, l.amount_currency,l.currency_id, c.symbol AS currency_code " \
        "FROM account_move_line l " \
        "LEFT JOIN account_journal j " \
            "ON (l.journal_id = j.id) " \
        "LEFT JOIN account_account acc " \
            "ON (l.account_id = acc.id) " \
        "LEFT JOIN res_currency c ON (l.currency_id=c.id)" \
        "LEFT JOIN account_move m ON (m.id=l.move_id)" \
        "LEFT JOIN account_invoice inv ON (inv.move_id = l.move_id)" \
        "WHERE l.partner_id = %s " \
            "AND l.account_id IN %s AND " + self.query +" " \
            "AND m.state IN %s " \
            " " + RECONCILE_TAG + " "\
            "ORDER BY l.date",
            (partner.id, tuple(self.account_ids), tuple(move_state)))

    res = self.cr.dictfetchall()
    count = 0.0
    sum = 0.0
    if self.initial_balance:
        sum = self.init_bal_sum
    for r in res:
        sum += r['debit'] - r['credit']
        r['progress'] = sum
        full_account.append(r)
    return full_account
```

I joind the data of table from which the I got the status of each invoice.